# Jinja macro doesn't render string + variable

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm trying to use this macro but doesn't render the "Dear user_name" into the macro, but if I pass only the variable it works.
Why does this happen?

layout.hmtl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

 <div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

macro.html

```
    {% macro paragraph(text="") %}
        <p>{{ text }}</p>
    {% endmacro %}
```

content.html

```
   {% extends 'layout.html' %}
   {% from 'macros/macro.html' import paragraph %}

   {% block content %}
     {{ paragraph(text="Dear user_name,") }}
   {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does `layout.html` look like? Since you're not placing your content (in `content.html`) in a named block, it's unlikely it will show up in your output.

Comment: @larsks fixed! now you can see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a variable named `user_name` and you'd like to use that in your template, you would need to move `user_name` outside of the literal string.  Instead of:

```
 {{ paragraph(text="Dear user_name,") }}
```

You would use:

```
 {{ paragraph(text="Dear " ~ user_name ~ ",") }}
```

Or:

```
 {{ paragraph(text="Dear {},".format(user_name)) }}
```

Using either of the above examples, this code:

```
import jinja2

e = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'))
t = e.get_template('content.html')
print(t.render(user_name='alice'))
```

When used with your templates, produces this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

 <div>


    <p>Dear alice,</p>


 </div>
</body>
</html>
```